# Ignore null/blank cells with filter

Tags: python, csv, lambda

I'm trying to filter the 22nd column with numbers between `0.10` and `1.00` into `Day.csv`. But some of those cells are blank with no number at all and cause an error:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Here is what I tried:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("AllData.csv"), delimiter=',') 
    filteredDay = filter(lambda p:0.10 <= float(p[23]) <= 1.00, reader)
    csv.writer(open(r"{}\Day.csv".format(queue),'w',newline =''),
               delimiter=',').writerows(filteredDay)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you therefore need your filter to return False when the cell in question contains no value? Try:

```
filteredDay = filter(lambda p: p[23] != "" and
                               0.10 <= float(p[23]) <= 1.00, reader)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary conditional to return `False` for blanks:

```
filteredDay = filter(lambda p: 0.10 <= float(p[23]) <= 1.00 if p[23] != '' 
                               else False, reader)
#                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `else False` is usually a good clue that your Boolean expression could be more efficiently rewritten

Comment: @holdenweb Yep, that's right. By using the expression itself